# jQuery is attr update on checkbox is not triggering change event

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a couple of checkboxes and a status box that tells you if at least 1 of the checkboxes are checked.

I also have a check All/None checkbox which works in toggling the checkboxes but it is not triggering the change event that is assigned to each of the checkboxes so the status never gets updated if the check All/None checkbox is used.

Here is my implementation:

http://jsfiddle.net/axl163/Fckvd/1/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
function toggleChecked(status) {
    $(".chkbx").each( function() {
        $(this).prop("checked", status).change(); // you have to trigger the event
    });
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2ej3W/1/)**

Comment: Yes I know =) Unfortunately, there is a 10 minute limit that I need to wait out before I can accept any answers.

Comment: @AllenLiu That is not unfortunate.. it is basically to give OP some time to review other answers too..  and it is just 10 minutes :)

Comment: @Vega - True! You two were just too fast.

Answer (score 6):

Any changes to an input element through a script WILL NOT trigger `onchange` event.

Alternatively you can trigger the `change()` while updating the changing the input like below,

```
$(this).prop("checked", status).change();
```

**Full code:**

```
function toggleChecked(status) {
    $(".chkbx").each( function() {
        $(this).prop("checked", status).change();
    });
}
```

Also use `.prop` instead of `.attr`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fckvd/3/)